# Delete anything between "&lt;" and "&gt;" in a String

Tags: java, regex, string

I have try `restString = restString.replaceAll("\\&lt;.*\\&gt;", "");`

and

`restString = restString.replaceAll("\\&lt;[^(\\&gt)]*\\&gt;", "");`.

Both seems don't work. I don't know if I could represent the meaning in the regular expression.

Comment: try only one slash, \&lt

Comment: @X-Pippes in Java to create \ literal we need to write it as `"\\"` since it is special character in String, just like it is special in regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your regex `non-greedy`:

```
restString = restString.replaceAll("(?s)&lt;.*?&gt;", "");
```

Also I used `(?s)` to make dot match newlines as well.

Comment: Thanks anubhava! Your approach works. I can see the main difference is that you use DOTALL mode to make dot match newlines. By the way, `&` is not an escape character??

Comment: You're welcome, Glad that it worked out. No `&` doesn't need to be escaped in regex.

Comment: If you have `lorem ispum <delete <> me> filler text` will this catch it?

Answer (score 2):

To solve this with a regular expression, you need to "look around" - use lookbehind and lookbefore:

```
restString = restString.replaceAll("(?<=&lt;).*(?=&gt;)", "");
```

lookaround-expressions will be evaluated by the regex-engine, but they won't be part of the match.
This way it's possible to delete everything BETWEEN &lt; and &gt;

If it should be nongreedy and able to match multiple lines, use expressions like anubhava has suggested:

```
restString = restString.replaceAll("(?s)(?<=&lt;).*?(?=&gt;)", "");
```

To learn more about lookarounds, visit this page: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Thanks for your answering! I haven't make it clear that I also need to delete `&lt;` and `&gt;`. The lookaround expression is definitely useful!